# Perl script to read a csv file from a particular row to end of file

Tags: perl, csv, perl-module

I have a CSV file `my.csv` with this content:

```
abc,yyy

efg,zzz

zsc,vvv

uvw,ggg
```

Depending upon the value in variable `$X` I need to read from that particular value until the end of the file. For example:

If `$X = efg`, the output would be:

```
efg,zzz

zsc,vvv

uvw,ggg
```

For `$X = zsc`:

```
zsc,vvv

uvw,ggg
```

This is the script I developed, which reads in a CSV file's whole content and displays it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {  
    chomp $line; 
    my @field = split "," , $line;
    print "$field[0] $field[1]";
}
```

Please help me with a script to display the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: Am very new to perl i just know to read the entire file and display...use strict;use warnings; my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n"; my $sum = 0;open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n"; while (my $line = <$data>) {  chomp $line;   my @fields = split "," , $line; print "$field[0] $fields[1]";}...please need a script to achieve whts mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

This solution skips lines 1 to the matching text, `if (1 .. /\b$start_word\b/)` and prints all lines from the matching text, to the end of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $start_word = 'efg';
my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (1 .. /\b$start_word\b/) {
        #print if /\b$start_word\b/;
        @data = [split /,/] if /\b$start_word\b/;
    }
    else {
        #print;
        push @data, [split /,/];
    }
}

# Do something with @data

__DATA__
abc,yyy
efg,zzz
zsc,vvv
uvw,ggg
```

Comment: "print if /\b$start_word\b/"; what does this line do...if the start word is efg....the output should be efg,zzz zsc,vvv uvw,ggg ....does this work...

Comment: *what does this line do*. This prints the current line IF the line contains the startword, 'efg', (and then every line after it to the end of file). Copy my code and run it to see that it works.

Comment: thanks for your help,it does display the fields aftr efg....is there some way i can extract these values one by one in a variable while parsing line by line csv, so that i can pass to another subroutine for further implementation on these values obatined...really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print lines where the first field is equal or larger than a specified value (e.g., `$X`), use a condition:

```
if ($field[0] >= $X) { 
    print ... 
}
```

Comment: the csv contents are changed...how about now...what if its all strings like above...is there any way to do so

Comment: @ysth  can you please check now..i modified my questionand included the sample script

Comment: can you please check now..i modified my questionand included the sample script

Comment: That is a different situation. I would use a flag variable that signals whether a certain string has already occurred, and then print the line if it has.